# Using offsetof with enum does not compile in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have the following piece of code that compiles fine in Visual Studio 2013, but not in Visual Studio 2015. 
On VS2015, I get the error "error C2057: expected constant expression"

```
#include <stddef.h>    

struct temp {
    int a;
    char b;
};

int main() {
    enum {TEST = (offsetof(struct temp, a)? 1 : 2)};
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it using the following command:
cl -nologo -FS -MD -EHsc -Od -D_DEBUG -Zi -c test.c

I looked at the stddef.h header and it seems like the offsetof macro has changed in VS 2015.
This piece of code compiles fine when I compile it using CPP flags:
cl -nologo -FS -MD -EHsc -Od -D_DEBUG -Zi -c test.c -TP

I am wondering how can I get this piece of code to work in Visual Studio 2015. Thanks!

Comment: It is a bug. Silly workaround is offsetof(struct temp, a) != 0 ? 1 : 2. Please report at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @HansPassant: I hope you don't mind me citing your comment.

Comment: @HansPassant, does that actually work?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I verified that in MSVC 2015 the OP's code fails, and Hans' code works.

Comment: This works as expected, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It seems that the VS2015 compiler is wrong.

From the standard:

> 7.19p3 "
>
> The macros are
>      ...
>
> ```
> offsetof(type, member-designator)
> ```
>
> which expands to an **integer constant expression**

and

> 6.6p3 (constraints for constant expressions): Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except ...

From both citations follows, that the expression above is a constant expression, thus every compliant compiler has to accept it where a constant expression is required, including the value of an *enum constant*.

**But** MSVC does not claim to be compliant to the C standard. In fact is is not even compliant to the 18 year old **previous** version of the standard (C99). Thus it might not support `offsetof`.

If it works in C++ does not proof anything; it is a different language.

---

#### Addition:

I assume the error stems from the `offsetof`. One reason this error message would show up is the macro is not defined during compilation. A C90 compiler will assume it is a function (no prototype, implicit declaration) defined in a different compilation unit. That would indeed make the expression non-constant for having a function-call (see 6.6p3 above). I don't think it is the conditional operator.

#### Update:

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725929/using-offsetof-with-enum-does-not-compile-in-visual-studio-2015/42726424#comment72572799_42725929) by @HansPassant, it is a bug in the macro in VS2015. A workaround is to explicitly compare the result of the macro:

```
(offsetof(struct temp, a) != 0) ? 1 : 2
```

**Added** by Weather Vane. This is the MSVC 2015 definition from `stddef.h`

```
// Define offsetof macro
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(_CRT_USE_BUILTIN_OFFSETOF)
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
    #else
        #define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&(((s*)0)->m))
    #endif
#else
    #define offsetof(s,m) __builtin_offsetof(s,m)
#endif
```

I do not know the significance of

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(_CRT_USE_BUILTIN_OFFSETOF)
```

Comment: @2501: Thanks, I just wonder why I got another unexplained downvote that instant.

Comment: You might want to glance at Hans Passant's comment to the question. (That's in reference to your edit. I have no idea why you attracted the downvote.)

Comment: Olaf from your commented question in another answer, MS does support [`offsetof` macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz4y9b9a.aspx) which requires `#include <stddef.h>` otherwise a different question would have been asked. But I can verify that in MSVC 2015 the top comment from @HansPassant is correct, and the OP's code fails.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Thanks for the info. Is the bugged macro code avalilable for inspection? I'd really curious how they messed it up like that. Even more, as it seems to have worked in the previous version ("never touch a running system").

Comment: @WeatherVane: Thanks. If you like to, feel free to add the information to my answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The normal macro looks ok in the first place (unless MSVC has a problem with dereferencing a null pointer constant), so I suspect the problem is the built-in variant. Things were so much easier when compilers were not **that** smart about optimisations .

Comment: I followed up the chain of included headers from `stddef.h` but did not find `#define _CRT_USE_BUILTIN_OFFSETOF`. MS has header files in many folders (not just 2): in their 32 bit stuff and 64 bit. I made a search of `#define _CRT_USE_BUILTIN_OFFSETOF` in the `*.h` files in those two folder trees, but to no avail. There are also header files without any file type extension, I do not know why, and I do not know how to search them without searching *every* file for text and that is not feasible unless I run it overnight.

Comment: Thanks, `enum {TEST = offsetof(struct temp, a)};` works as well. Its just a combination of using offset of with the ternary operator that doesn't compile.

Comment: @shank22 that does not give `2` but `0`. But you set off a huge discussion!

Comment: @WeatherVane that is correct. So the bug seems to be in the built-in macro?

Comment: The bug seems to be you were using a conditional statement to ascertain a  value. As you have seen, the macro otherwise works.

Comment: Yes that seems like it.

Comment: @shank22: You could try to use the builtin directly to make sure it is the origin of the problems. Also using conditional compilation before&after the include could verify `_CRT_USE_BUILTIN_OFFSETOF` is defined (although it does not guarantee there is no `undef`ing in the standard headers). But more can only be answered by Microsoft. On a personal note, as MSVC is not standard compliant anyway, I'd consider using a modern compiler like gcc or clang. C99 and C11 introduced quite some more features to write better code.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the error "error C2057: expected constant expression"

VS appears to be non-conforming in this regard.  At minimum, it is applying an unconventional interpretation of the rules for integer constant expressions.  MS has never claimed that its C implementation conforms to any version of the standard -- and it is known not to do -- but inasmuch as VS2013 did this differently, I'd account VS2015's behavior a bug.

The complaint presumably pertains to the initializer for enum constant `TEST`.  C requires the value to have the form of an "[integer constant expression](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6)", and a ternary operation can absolutely be an integer constant expression if its operands are suitable.  I presume that MSVC is rejecting the code because of the use of the `offsetof()` macro, but the standard [expressly specifies](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19) that that macro itself expands to an integer constant expression (the link is to a C2011 draft, but all previous releases of the standard have said this).

In addition to the general requirements for constant expressions:

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment,
>   decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are
>   contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.
>
> Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the
>   range of representable values for its type.

, *integer* constant expressions are subject to these restrictions:

> An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall
>   only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
>   character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
>   constants, _Alignof expressions, and floating constants that are the
>   immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant
>   expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types,
>   except as part of an operand to the sizeof or _Alignof operator.

The only way I can parse all that to disallow your code is to distinguish between "integer constant" and "integer constant *expression*" for the allowed operands of an integer constant expression.  I do not think that is the intent of the standard, however, and I am unaware of any implementation that takes that interpretation -- to the best of my knowledge, even MSVC itself does not take that interpretation in other contexts.

As to your actual question,

> I am wondering how can I get this piece of code to work in Visual Studio 2015.

, unless there's some possibility that the definition of `struct temp` varies, I'd evaluate the whole ternary expression manually.  The offset of the first member of a structure is required to be 0, so I'd replace your code with

```
enum {TEST = 2};
```

Alternatively, in comments, @HansPassant suggests this workaround:

```
enum { TEST = (offsetof(struct temp, a) != 0) ? 1 : 2 };
```

If that doesn't work for you then the best solution available is probably to use a different (version of the) compiler.